# Keep getting update notifcations despite there is nothing to update

Tags: updates

Seems like this issue persists no matter how many times I update. As I enter my dashboard almost 100% of the times I get a notification on a WordPress update. It also shows at the bottom of the page. It disappears as soon as I hit the button "check again" or sometimes just by entering the updates page.

Why does it happen so often? Its annoying and I would like to know if there is any easy fix for this.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you talking about the DB upgrade or the update itself? Have you seen [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141731/wordpress-3-9-database-update-infinite-loop)? I suspect this is probably a cache issue, is this possible?

Comment: No, it always says that there is a new version of wordpress available. But as soon as I reload the page it goes back to "you have the latest version installed". It sometimes disappears just by entering the updates page.

Comment: Do you have caching on the Server? Have a look at [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141651/cant-update-wordpress-need-to-reboot-the-vps?rq=1)

Comment: I dont know. Its a shared server. Anyway, I tried the advice given by the user of that post. Lets see how it works. Thank you.

Comment: No, it didnt work. I logged in today and Im seeing the update core notification despite I have the latest version. By entering the update page it disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem and found that W3 Total Cache was the culprit.  Deactivating and reactivating the plugin cured the problem.  Hat tip to [this forum](https://theadminzone.com/threads/wordpress-says-1-update-but-there-is-no-update.116617/) for the clue.